# Tensorboard Not Displaying Projector

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I've been trying to get a working example of a Tensorboard Projection via Google Colab, but have not yet found something that works. I'd like to edit this document to fit a project of mind that I'm working on (I want to map images in a 3d space).

Currently, even the Colab document found in the Tensorboard  Embedding Projector guide fails to display when I run the authors code. It is not reproducible. Neither is any of the other examples that I've worked through (I'm on #4 currently).

Guide here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_projector_plugin

Notebook here: https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/tensorboard_projector_plugin.ipynb

End in mind here (specifically the MNIST with Images Tensor): [http://projector.tensorflow.org/?_gl=1*zdq65m*_ga*Njg5MjIyMDI2LjE2OTAyMDcyMjQ.*_ga_W0YLR4190T*MTY5MDM5MTc2NC43LjEuMTY5MDM5MTgxMC4wLjAuMA..[enter](http://projector.tensorflow.org/?_gl=1*zdq65m*_ga*Njg5MjIyMDI2LjE2OTAyMDcyMjQ.*_ga_W0YLR4190T*MTY5MDM5MTc2NC43LjEuMTY5MDM5MTgxMC4wLjAuMA..%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dFys.png)

Am I missing something here that I need to change within my Colab to make these boards display? I keep getting a "No image data was found" error, and all previous attempts to find a ready solution on the forums have failed.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!